# How to randomize .class names inside .hasClass() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code of this:

```
$(".user-items").each(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("don't know the code yet")) {
    $(this).fadeIn();
  } else {
    $(this).fadeOut();
  }
});
```

but I wanted it to work like this:

```
$(".user-items").each(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass(".people OR .photos OR .videos")) {
    $(this).fadeIn();
  } else {
    $(this).fadeOut();
  }
});
```

I wanted to randomize the **3 classes** in every `.each()` loop and make all matched elements **fadeIn/fadeOut**

**Note*: The "OR" inside `.hasClass` is just an interpretation of how I wanted it to work**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="user-items people">People</a>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="user-items photos">Photo</a>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="user-items videos">Videos</a>
...
...
...
lots of more .user-items classes with 3 given classes: .people, .photos, .videos
```

Thank you

Comment: Don't put your `OR` logic inside of `hasClass`, just do multiple `hasClass()` and put the `OR` between.

    `var $t = $(this);
    if ($t.hasClass("People") || $t.hasClass("Photos") || $t.hasClass("Videos"))`  Though I'm not quite understanding where the "random" comes into play here.

Comment: Are you asking how to select a random word (class name) from a list of words?

Comment: Please see my edit above. Thanks ! @freedomn-m No I wanted to select random .class  names

Comment: @TylerRoper Sorry if I confuse you. That was only an interpretation on how I wanted it to work inside that .hasClass(). Please see my edit above. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use an array of classes then `random()` method to get every time a random class like :

```js
var classes = ['photos', 'videos', 'people'];

$(".user-items").each(function() {
  var random_class = classes[Math.floor((Math.random() * classes.length) + 0)];

  console.log(random_class);

  if ($(this).hasClass(random_class)) {
    $(this).fadeIn();
  } else {
    $(this).fadeOut();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="user-items people">People</a>
<br>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="user-items photos">Photo</a>
<br>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="user-items videos">Videos</a>
```

Comment: Could you please add your HTML structure.

Comment: Check my update.. doesn't make much since but may helps.

Comment: Great, Glad I could help brother.